# 3rd Party React Component Causing Warning

Tags: reactjs, dom, components

New React developer here so please pardon me if the question is a bit silly. I'm using a 3rd party React component called twitter-like-button ([link to repo](https://github.com/skychavda/twitter-like-button)) and it's been working fine for my purpose. The only very slight issue is that I'm getting an "Invalid DOM property" warning in my dev tool:

`Warning: Invalid DOM property 'fill-rule. Did you mean 'fillRule'?`

This would've been a no-brainer fix as it tells you what you need to change but since it's a 3rd party component installed with npm... I don't have access to change any of its properties.

Currently I have two options in mind which is either a) contact the owner or b) submit a change suggestion on GitHub (I'm not even sure if it's the correct/best route).

So I'm just wondering if there are other options that a noob like me may not be aware of, like something I can do within my project to resolve the warning.

Thank you and cheers!

**Things I've done:**
I read the doc about the component and tried applying 'fillRule' property directly to the component but it's not a prop that it takes so it did not do anything. I reviewed the actual component's code on GitHub and did find 'fill-rule' used in the tag, but I'm unsure if it's correct to propose changes on GitHub like that (I'm also unsure if I'm misunderstanding or misusing the component in some way).

Comment: If not in our hands, I would go for **b)**  but as an issue ...

Comment: Thank you KcH! I figured that's as much as we can do when we're using a 3rd party component but I was 100% sure. I think I might do just that! Thanks a ton!